# Communicating form validation across controllers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI Router and have two forms on the same page. I would like the submit button to be disabled if either form is not valid. I'm not sure how to communicate this information from controller A to controller B. In other words, how do I communicate to controller B that `{{paymentForm.$invalid}}` in form 1 is no longer true?

Form 1

```
<form name="paymentForm" novalidate >

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group" >

        <label class="control-label" for="first-name">First Name</label>
        <input autofocus type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName" ng-model="contactForm.contact.firstName"
           placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label for="middle-name">Initial</label>
        <input type="text" id="middle-name" name="middleName" ng-model="contactForm.contact.middleName"
           placeholder="Initial" class="form-control" >

    </div>
```

Form 2

```
<form novalidate name="myForm" >
  <p class="text-muted" ng-bind="myForm.number"></p>

<div class="form-group" >
<label class="control-label" for="cardnumber">Card number</label>
<div class="input-group">
<input id="cardnumber" type="text" placeholder="Card Number" name="cardnumber" class="form-control input-block-level" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="myForm.expiry.$card.type" required />
```

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || paymentForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) to nest these two forms into a parent form. This way if any of the field within the two child forms are invalid, the parent form will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Option. 1 : use nested forms and diSable the button parentForm.$invalid where parentForm is the name of your outer form

Option. 2 :write a service to communicate between the 2 controllers.

I would do this in 2 situations,
A) if you plan to add more for multiple forms to the same view and your disabling logic is not as straight forward as checking only for validity of parent form,
B ) Your disabling logic is simple and for some reason you can not or you don't want to nest these 2 forms 
C ) Your forms are in 2 intirely different views which are included within a parent view and you are not able to nest them.

If we plan to write a common service, have flag variables to indicate validity of a each of your forms. Inject this service in both of your controllers!

Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you. How would I use a service so that it knows when the form is no longer invalid? There's no next or submit button on the first form.